# Webdriver drag-and-drop causes undefined behaviour?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[The protocol spec for Webdriver has this to say on the `buttonDown` action](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#sessionsessionidbuttondown) (emphasis mine):

> Click and hold the left mouse button (at the coordinates set by the last `moveto` command). Note that the next mouse-related command that should follow is `buttonup`. **Any other mouse command (such as click or another call to `buttondown`) will yield undefined behaviour.**

It seems reasonable that `buttonDown` then `click` should result in undefined behaviour, but the common use case for `buttonDown` is to follow it with a `moveto` to simulate a drag. I'd count `moveto` as a mouse command which isn't `buttonUp` and therefore this also results in undefined behaviour.

Is this just poor wording in the spec or is `buttonDown` then `moveto` not a legal sequence?

Comment: fyi, your doc-link is out-of-date.  the selenium doc has since moved to the github wiki [here](http://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol)

Comment: Thanks, updated. And opened as an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luke Inman-Semerau from the Selenium Github project (@lukeis) tells me that it is indeed just poor wording:

> That's just poor wording... and not likely to be updated, since we've been working on the W3C spec -
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/
>
> the JSONWireProtocol document is essentially just left there for historical reference.

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1512